# SBT command to check what memory options are on use

Tags: scala, command-line, sbt, jvm-arguments

After modifying the sbtconfig.txt file I would like to know if there is any command in SBT that would allow me to check if this values are really in effect.

After typing "settings -V" I see lots of options but none of them seem helpful:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Try `sbt -v` (lowercase v)

I got this on linux:

```
$ sbt -v                                                                                                                             master
[process_args] java_version = '1.8.0_112'
# Executing command line:
java
-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
-Xms1G
-Xmx6G
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=250M
-XX:+TieredCompilation
-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true
-jar
/usr/share/sbt/bin/sbt-launch.jar
```